# How can I make Webpack 5 available in my Docker container?

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, docker-compose, webpack-5

I am trying to use the latest webpack version that was just released last October 2020, which is v5, but I am having trouble as docker cannot find webpack. But if I used the earlier versions of webpack like v4 it works. I would like to use the latest webpack with docker in my current project. How can I fix this? How can I make webpack v5 be available in my docker container. Thank you.

This is the output if I run `docker-compose up`:

```
    Attaching to frontend-react2_app_1
    app_1  | 
    app_1  | > frontend-react2@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
    app_1  | > webpack serve --mode=development
    app_1  | 
    app_1  | sh: webpack: not found
    app_1  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    app_1  | npm ERR! syscall spawn
    app_1  | npm ERR! file sh
    app_1  | npm ERR! errno ENOENT
    app_1  | npm ERR! frontend-react2@1.0.0 start: `webpack serve --mode=development`
    app_1  | npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
    app_1  | npm ERR! 
    app_1  | npm ERR! Failed at the frontend-react2@1.0.0 start script.
    app_1  | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    app_1  | 
    app_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    app_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-06T11_30_34_220Z-debug.log
```

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "frontend-react2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode=development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "lint": "eslint --fix src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.5",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.41.24",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.9",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14.15-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use volumes in your docker compose?

Comment: we use a similar approach for developers so that they can use a prod-life environment without tampering with the machine itself. On production, we just deploy without the volumes.

Comment: @NikitaChayka I am just new to docker and not exactly sure why tho. I am thinking that it might help docker detect the changes I have made in my code.

Comment: If i am not wrong then what you doing is placing /usr/src/app as /use/src/app/node_modules in docker, which is a mistake, cause you are losing node_modules folder in docker in this case.

Comment: @NikitaChayka: it's not a mistake and the content is not lost. The content of that folder is simply taken from the image and stored in a nameless volume. Since the node_modules are OS dependend, you cannot simply re-use what's already stored on your machine.

Comment: The `volumes:` instruct Docker to ignore any changes in the image's `node_modules` directory and always use what was there the very first time you ran the container.  Indeed, the volume mounts you have overwrite all of the work the `Dockerfile` does with volume mounts.  If you delete the `volumes:`, does it work correctly?  (It should be very easy to install Node to get a local live-development environment.)